# Is it good to receive all markers and their relevant infoWindow in one request? - google map iOS sdk

Tags: ios, google-maps

I have a google map in my iOS app that every time user drags map, a request will be sent to get markers coordinate. My guy at backend says he wants to send infoWindow data relevant to all markers at the same time, so only one request is sent every time. But I say due to battery and memory usage, in every drag only markers coordinates should be received and when the user taps on a marker relevant infoWindow data to that marker should be received. So which is better for implementation?

Comment: Please let us know the number of markers, you try to add on the map at the same time.

Comment: It is different based on user search but its range is between 100 to 4000 @ShubhamNarang

Answer (score 0):

If it's only for 100 to 400 markers at a time.

you can fetch all markers in one go. And then set all markers at the same time.

For fetching 100 to 400 markers from backend will not take more than 1 to 2 seconds.

Your approach is not user-friendly.

Please share your thoughts on the same.

Comment: markers receive at the same time. I'm talking about infoWindows details relevant to each marker. I mean for example 400 marker and their infoWindow detail in one request OR 400 markers in one request and request for each infoWindow on user demand

Comment: That's not a good approach if you request an info detail on click of Marker.
It will make the application response time, And also more chance of failure.

Fetching all markers and info detail in a single API, is a good approach, and minimize the chances of failure.